# Is there a way to select a tenant in Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ?

Tags: azure, intellij-idea, azure-java-tools

Is there anyway to select a tenant that is not default when I log in via Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ ?

Once I sign in, there seems to be no way to change the tenant. How do I do that ?

It says this has been fixed in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-tools-for-java/issues/4456), but provides no details on how to use the functionality.

[image]

Comment: Did you check this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/toolkit-for-intellij/sign-in-instructions#sign-in-to-your-azure-account-with-azure-cli)

Comment: @PravallikaKothaveerannagari yes, as you can see there is no way to select a TENANT there. Only way to change subscriptions.

Comment: I'm not sure about selecting a tenant, but if you know the Tenant ID, you can login.

Comment: @PravallikaKothaveerannagari I believe you are referring to the `Service Principal` login which asks for the Tenant ID. That would work except I have no access to the `Azure AD` - which is needed for the `Client ID`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are right. AFAIK, there is only one way i.e., via Service Principal and yes you should have access to do so.

Comment: @PravallikaKothaveerannagari Where would I get my Client ID from ?

Comment: you have to register your application in Active Directory> App registration. Then you'll be able to see the details like client ID and Tenant ID. Check this [image](https://i.imgur.com/4u3y8cT.png) and also check the answer which I have provided below.

Answer (score 0):

It is marked as feature request but not yet implemented this way of Signing of selecting a tenant in IntelliJ IDE Toolkit as described in this GitHub Issue #[4456](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-tools-for-java/issues/4456) you have mentioned.

From this Issue, I have traversed the previous ticket issues given at the end of each Ticket Page and then I came to know this is marked as feature-request type but not fixed yet and they have provided the [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/toolkit-for-intellij/sign-in-instructions) everywhere which provides the information on available ways of Sign-in instructions in IntelliJ IDE ToolKit.